# How to take set multiple variables using argparse, both required and optional variables?

Tags: python, argparse, option-type

How do you deal with multiple inputs via `argparse`, especially when there are default inputs and optional inputs?

Within my script `file.py`, users must input two parameters, which I have in a list

```
parameters_list = [parameter1, parameter2, parameter3]

parameter1 = ""  # normally in the script, I would set these
parameter2 = ""
parameter3 = ""
```

The third parameter `parameter3` is a default parameter.

Now, to my mind, users could include the flags at run time `python file.py --parameters = 'parameter1', 'parameter2'`

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('parameters', nargs = '*', help = 'input program parameters')
params = parser.parse_args()
```

However

1. This doesn't parse how users have input the parameters, like:

   `--parameters = 'parameter1', 'parameter2'`
2. How do you deal with the default parameter `parameter3`?

   At the moment, this will throw at error, as the variable `parameter3` has been defined in the script, but isn't defined by `argparse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to parse out the parameters as comma separated values.

```
import argparse
import sys
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--parameters',nargs='*',help="input program parameters")
args,unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
if(unknown):
   print("Do not use spaces!")
   sys.exit()
parameters = args.parameters
parameters = parameters[0].split(',')
parameter1 = parameters[0]
parameter2 = parameters[1]
parameter3 = "your_value" if len(parameters) < 3 else params[2]
```

Of course the user would have to input the params as (no spaces):

```
--parameters='parameter1','parameter2','parameter3'
```

Also note that to use `--parameters` the argument you add to the parser must match.

Comment: And if the user input spaces, what would be the result?

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it would still work,  but the `params = params.split(',')` would fail.so just taking that line out may work. "'*'. All command-line arguments present are gathered into a list."

Comment: You're saying `parse_args()` alone does the job, and `parse_args().split(',')` will parse these values incorrectly?

Comment: I misspoke, after trying it out a space trows a wrench in the whole thing. so to get it working you need `--paramaters='param1','param2'` with no spaces, as in the answer, also updated the answer to fix a problem I found (`params = parser.parse_args()` gives a list of all arguments, and if you want to use `--paramters=...` the argument should match in argparse)

Comment: Let's say I'm releasing this as software, and I wanted to catch users for making the mistake of including spaces---what would be the best way to stop this bug?

Comment: Updated answer again, had a few unforseen bugs. To answer your question, you can use the following (assuming you are using the sys module for `sys.exit()`) 
`args,unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
 if(unknown):
    print("Do not use spaces!")
    sys.exit()
`

Answer (score 2):

I would just define separate parameters for each:

```
p = ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("arg1")
p.add_argument("arg2")
p.add_argument("arg3", default=5, nargs='?')
```

and require calls like

```
$ python file.py 3 2
$ python file.py 3 2 6
```